# Copy all contents (recursive) of a folder from one s3 bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to copy all files from one S3 Folder to another in different buckets. I was able to come to a solution where one could list all objects and copy them to different bucket path. Is there any other better solution to this problem?

P.S: I have to do this using AWS SDK (Javascript)

Comment: Have you considered [Amazon S3 Batch Operations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working solution by listing objects in the source bucket and then copying each object to the destination bucket, then that's great!

Some other options:

- Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` commands, which effectively is the same as your solution but somebody has written the code
- Use [Cross-Region Replication - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html), but the buckets must be in different regions
- Configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new file is created. Program the Lambda function to copy the file immediately. The result is near-instant copying of files rather than having to copy them in batches at regular intervals.